# Evaluate conditions passed as arguments to custom function in Google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to create a custom function that accepts conditions as arguments like the **FILTER()** function does, e.g. :

```
LARGEST_STREAK(Data, Winnings > 0)
LARGEST_STREAK(Data, Winnings > 0, Sports = "Football")
```

(Data, Winnings and Sports being Named ranges).

Would you have examples of functions that do that ? The best would be the source code of the FILTER() function but I'm not even sure it's Javascript running behind for buit-in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments that a custom function receives are not ranges, they are JavaScript values or double arrays. For example, `customfunction(A1:A3, B2:D2)` will receive arguments `[[x], [y], [z]]` and `[[x,y,z]]` where x,y,z are values stored in those cells.

In particular, arrays can be arrays of booleans, which can then be used in JavaScript's own `filter` method. Here is a re-implementation of `FILTER` function as a custom function:

```
function myFilter(arr, conditions) {
  if (conditions.length == 1) {
    return arr.map(function (row) {
      return row.filter(function (_, i) {
        return conditions[0][i];
      });
    });
  }
  else {
    return arr.filter(function (_, i) {
      return conditions[i][0];
    });
  }
}
```

To use this with comparisons, you need  `arrayformula` wrapper:

```
=arrayformula(myfilter(A1:C10, D1:D10 > 5))
```

The reason is that without the wrapper, `D1:D10 > 5` returns the same as `D1 > 5`. The built-in `FILTER` function does not need such as wrapper, since it's already known to be a function that works with arrays.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand when the "conditions.length == 1" scope is used.

Also what about multiple conditions, How would the conditions array look like ?

Comment: The array of conditions in filter must be one dimensional: either a row or a column. length == 1 indicates a row, `[[x,y,z]]`. Otherwise it's a column, `[[x], [y], [z]]`. If you had multiple conditions, you'd have `return conditions[0][i] && moreConditions[0][i];` ...